# Populating a python tuple with strings stored in different keys across multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the following data structures:

```
x = {'name': 'x', 'alias': ['test']}
y = {'name': 'y', 'alias': ['run', 'log']}
z = (x, y)
```

And now I would like to populate a tuple with all of the name and alias strings, like so:

```
result = ('x', 'y', 'test', 'run', 'log')
```

The order is not important. I have tried a seemingly interminable number of comprehension statements, but I keep ending up with a tuple of lists, or a mixture of strings and lists, or just an error. I'm looking for something like this:

```
try_result = tuple(dname['name'] for dname in z) 
    + tuple(x for x in dname['alias'] for dname in z)
```

Even though I know the "nested" `for` statements at the end there are invalid, I am looking for a way to mimic that logic, first looking through an `alias` list and taking all of its strings before moving on to the next dictionary to do the same.

Comment: `result` should probably be a list, not a tuple, since your data there is homogeneous.

Comment: Here: `tuple(x for x in dname['alias'] for dname in z)` you mixed the order. It should be `tuple(x for dname in z for x in dname['alias'])`.

Comment: You've done it! Thank you! I didn't know this was the order of operations for comprehension statements like this. Also, I needed it to be a tuple because I needed it to be immutable, for reasons irrelevant to the problem. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following comprehension:

```
tuple(i for dct in z for i in [dct['name'], *dct['alias']])
# ('x', 'test', 'y', 'run', 'log')
```

Comment: This is also great. Since the answer from the comments wasn't proposed as a solution, I'll accept this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not the optimal way to do it. But it works

```
result = []
for i in z: 
   result.append(i['name'])
for i in z:
   for k in i['alias']:
      result.append(k)
result = tuple(result)
print(result)
```

> ```
>  ('x', 'y', 'test', 'run', 'log')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_alias = [[dname.get('name')] + dname.get('alias') for dname in z)]
>>> name_alias
>>> [['x', 'test'], ['y', 'run', 'log']]
```

Then you can flat the list into tuple:

```
result = []
for names in name_alias:
    result.extend(names)

>>> tuple(result)
>>> ('x', 'test', 'y', 'run', 'log')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_all = []
for dname in z:
    list_all.append(dname['name'])
    for a in dname['alias']:
        list_all.append(a)
result = tuple(list_all)
print(result)
```